# bytes and strings issue with pandas and csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, encoding, tweepy

The image contains the type of csv file present. I wish to eliminate all the encoded characters.

I downloaded tweets by encoding them in utf-8 format. The type of the file should technically be a byte. However while reading the file through csv, the tweets again get converted to a string. Anyway which I can tackle the problem?

I have a string of a byte of a string.

Example string="b'my bytes are in string format``/x88/x99/x56'"

code

`1)bytes(str(df['Tweet']),'utf-8')

2)df['Tweet'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

Comment: What did you try? also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: 1)bytes(str(df['Tweet']),'utf-8')) 


import ast
2)df['Tweet'].apply(ast.literal_eval) 


I tried these two techniques, both of them didnt work

Comment: `"/x88/x99/x56"` is an ASCII string. On the other hand, `b'\x88\x99\x56'.decode('cp1252')` returns `'ˆ™V'`. Please  [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JosefZ  I have edited with a screenshot, i hope you understand the doubt.

Comment: **1st** Read again [mcve]  article - pictures are (mostly) useless. Share your code and _sanitized_ data (a [mcve])!